# Nulable аннотация показывает ошибку в Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dagger2, dagger

У меня есть метод который может вернуть nullable обьект , я добавляю соответствующую аннотацию в метод и во все остальные методы которые используют этот обьект, но все равно получаю ошибку

```
Error:(17, 7) error: services.objects.response.CallServicePart is not 
nullable, but is being provided by 
@ui.dagger.dynamicFormComponent.PerDynamicForm @Provides 
@android.support.annotation.Nullable 
services.objects.response.CallServicePart 
ui.dagger.dynamicFormComponent.DynamicModule
.getCallServicePart(models.AppModel)
at:     services.objects.response.CallServicePart is injected at
ui.fragments.DynamicFormFragment.mServicePart
ui.fragments.DynamicFormFragment is injected at
ui.dagger.dynamicFormComponent.DynamicFormComponent.inject(iFragment)
```

Вот мой модуль

```
@Module
public class DynamicModule
{

...///

@PerDynamicForm
@Provides
@Nullable
CallServicePart getCallServicePart(AppModel iAppModel)
{
    return iAppModel.getServicePart();
}

@PerDynamicForm
@Provides
@Nullable
ServicePartFormQuestionsManager getServicePartFormQuestionsManager(@CallNumber long iCallNumber, @Nullable CallServicePart iServicePart)
{
    ServicePartFormQuestionsManager manager = null;

    if (iServicePart != null)
    {
        manager = CallsManager.getInstance().getOpenCallData(iCallNumber).getServicePartFormQuestionManagerForPartCode(iServicePart.getPartCode());
    }

    return manager;
}

...///
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: А этот метод `nullable`: `iAppModel.getServicePart()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аннотация `@Nullable` говорит о том, что возвращаемое значение параметра, поля или метода может быть .

- If a {@code @Provides} method is marked {@code @Nullable}, Dagger will *only*
- allow injection into sites that are marked {@code @Nullable} as well. A component that
- attempts to pair a {@code @Nullable} provision with a non-{@code @Nullable} injection site
- will fail to compile.

Если метод отмечен как `@Nullabl`e, Dagger допускает инъекцию только на ссылки с отметкой @Nullable. Компонент, который пытается скомпилировать условие `@Nullable` с помощью команды non@Nullable, зафейлится.

```
Error:(17, 7) error: services.objects.response.CallServicePart is not 
nullable
```

Вот он и ругается, проверьте что класс имеет аннотации, на всякий случай сделайте clean project и rebuild.

Comment: ну да, всё я не так понял, перечитал ещё раз. Сейчас дополню

Comment: Да , но в вопросе видно же , что `CallServicePart` отмечен как `Nullable`, или не так